# Hyper-V: NAT not functioning / guest cannot access internet

Tags: networking, hyper-v, nat, freebsd, windows-11

I'm running Windows 11 Pro, and have set up a FreeBSD VM under Hyper-V. Initially, the VM was using the default virtual switch, and internet access from the VM worked correctly. But in an attempt to prevent the VM's IP address from changing on each reboot, I attempted to create a new virtual switch and set up a static IP address with NAT. Currently, the host and guest can ping each other but the guest cannot ping anything through the host's wifi connection. The VM *is* set up to use the correct virtual switch in Hyper-V.

I followed [this guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/setup-nat-network) on the Microsoft website to set up the NAT, and then I edited `/etc/rc.conf` on the FreeBSD VM, as follows:

```
ifconfig_DEFAULT="inet 192.168.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0"
defaultrouter="192.168.0.1"
```

Here is the host-side configuration info on the virtual switch, static IP address, and NAT:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-vmswitch

Name           SwitchType NetAdapterInterfaceDescription
----           ---------- ------------------------------
LocalNat       Internal
Default Switch Internal


PS C:\Windows\system32> get-netadapter

Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------
vEthernet (LocalNat)      Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2          16 Up
Bluetooth Network Conn... Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Netw...      27 Discon...
Wi-Fi                     Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX210 160MHz                8 Up
vEthernet (Default Swi... Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter             33 Up


PS C:\Windows\system32> get-netipaddress -InterfaceIndex 16


IPAddress         : fe80::ac90:94a:c07b:35fc%16
InterfaceIndex    : 16
InterfaceAlias    : vEthernet (LocalNat)
AddressFamily     : IPv6
Type              : Unicast
PrefixLength      : 64
PrefixOrigin      : WellKnown
SuffixOrigin      : Link
AddressState      : Preferred
ValidLifetime     : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
PreferredLifetime : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
SkipAsSource      : False
PolicyStore       : ActiveStore

IPAddress         : 192.168.0.1
InterfaceIndex    : 16
InterfaceAlias    : vEthernet (LocalNat)
AddressFamily     : IPv4
Type              : Unicast
PrefixLength      : 24
PrefixOrigin      : Manual
SuffixOrigin      : Manual
AddressState      : Preferred
ValidLifetime     : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
PreferredLifetime : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
SkipAsSource      : False
PolicyStore       : ActiveStore



PS C:\Windows\system32> get-netnat


Name                             : HyperV-NatNetwork
ExternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix :
InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix : 192.168.0.0/24
IcmpQueryTimeout                 : 30
TcpEstablishedConnectionTimeout  : 1800
TcpTransientConnectionTimeout    : 120
TcpFilteringBehavior             : AddressDependentFiltering
UdpFilteringBehavior             : AddressDependentFiltering
UdpIdleSessionTimeout            : 120
UdpInboundRefresh                : False
Store                            : Local
Active                           : True
```

And here's the output of `netstat` on the VM:

```
$ netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags     Netif Expire
default            192.168.0.1        UGS         lo0
127.0.0.1          link#1             UH          lo0
192.168.0.0/24     link#2             U           hn0
192.168.0.2        link#1             UHS         lo0

Internet6:
Destination                       Gateway                       Flags     Netif Expire
::/96                             ::1                           UGRS        lo0
::1                               link#1                        UHS         lo0
::ffff:0.0.0.0/96                 ::1                           UGRS        lo0
fe80::/10                         ::1                           UGRS        lo0
fe80::%lo0/64                     link#1                        U           lo0
fe80::1%lo0                       link#1                        UHS         lo0
fe80::%hn0/64                     link#2                        U           hn0
fe80::215:5dff:fec8:704%hn0       link#2                        UHS         lo0
ff02::/16                         ::1                           UGRS        lo0
```

What have I done wrong?

**EDIT / SOLUTION**: as stated in the accepted answer, I'm trying to do the wrong thing here. My solution was to keep the virtual switch outlined here, and add a second network interface to the VM, putting that one on the default network. External traffic routes through the default interface, and gets a different IP address whenever Hyper-V feels like it, and traffic from the host to the guest can use the internal virtual switch, where the guest has a static IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in an attempt to prevent the VM's IP address from changing on each
> reboot, I attempted to create a new virtual switch and set up a static
> IP address with NAT

This is an improper use of NAT in Hyper-V or any other like App such as VMware.

NAT is for DHCP and IP addresses will change occasionally.

If you wish to have a Static IP address, you can set up an External Network Switch in Hyper-V (so Bridged Network) and then the Guest will get an IP on the Host Network Router. That can be Static if you wish.

I have tested this on Windows 11 Pro, Hyper-V, and a Linux Guest.

Comment: To clarify, I only want the VM's IP address to be "static" from the point of view of the host. This is on a laptop - I really just want to avoid having to look up the guest's IP address to SSH into it all the time. This being the case, would you still recommend going the route you've described?

Comment: Yes, you need the External Switch to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check how your NAT is using ExternalAddresses.
It can be done with following powershell command:

```
Get-NetNatExternalAddress
```

On my system I noticed the first entries were actually local loopback and other virtual switch addresses (which did not have access to the outside world).
I solved it by simply by removing all ExternalAddresses in my NAT except one last IPAddress which had internet connectivity.
Repeat following command for any IPAddress that is not routable:

```
Remove-NetNatExternalAddress -ExternalAddressID <ID>
```

This should fix your problem and the NAT will start handling outgoing traffic through the right interface.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to access the virtual machine by a static address without needing a static IP on Default switch is to use the hostname of virtual machine name with `.mshome.net` appended, e.g. `my-vm.mshome.net`. The default switch updates this mapping in your hosts.ics file whenever it assigns a DHCP IP to the VM.

As a downside, this mapping is only available in the hosting Windows OS. Other virtual machines or a Linux running on WLS cannot resolve it via DNS queries.