How can I make the virtual internal NAT switch work on a Hyper-V VM?
I didn't want to use the Hyper-V default network switch, because the IP address keeps changing, so I read that I need to create a new static internal switch.
I then created a NAT switch using the following guide: Set up a NAT network
And I gave it two DNS servers to use (1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8).
I am clearly missing something, because now I have a switch on Windows that is "Unidentified network" (I gave it a completely different IP address range from the ISP one—the ISP range is 192.168.14.x and I gave the NAT 10.0.0.x, but I thought it should be different like that default Hyper-V IP address range), and also when I type ip addr show inside the Ubuntu VM, I don't see any IPv4 address. And from what I read—I need to assign it a static IP address now that I am not using the default switch.
However, I am not sure how to do it, and also I am not sure if it's a problem that I see "Unidentified Network" on Windows as well.
I feel like this is one of the things I've completely misunderstood and going the wrong direction. Or, maybe everything is working and I just need to set a static IP inside Ubuntu?
The question is this: How to set a new switch to the Hyper-V manager to replace the default one, such that I will be able to set static IP address inside the (Ubuntu) VM, with different IP range than the ISP one. (Because right now with the default switch, it keeps changing the IPv4 addresses inside the VM)
Update: I found this answer on another post saying that I am doing something completely wrong: https://superuser.com/a/1690940/1615431
Is that true? I must do external switch instead?

It would be better with a direct question (in the body).

Is my last edit alright? I asked the question at the bottom to make it more direct and clear
